# Is there a way to check if charachters in a string is contained in an array of charachter - NO VBA

Tags: excel

I have a long string in excel. I need to check if every char of the string match an array of char.
For example:

```
Array of allowed char: "i a m n o t I t e r s d *space*" --> CHECK OK
"I am not interested" --> check ok
"I am not very interested" --> check failed : v and y non allowed
```

I have tried with find or match but they just look for the first occureence,....

Comment: Want to do that with only a formula? No VBA?

Comment: And space does not count either way?

Comment: yeah, no VBA.... I can't use it. space is an allowed char sorry... :(
Charachters allowed is a cell every char...

Comment: The problem is with the capitalization, very few formulas care about matching case.  Find is one, but that would require changing to a list of unacceptable characters.

Comment: we can try to ignore capitalization, but we can't change to a list of unacceptable char

Comment: Why can't you use VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a case-sensitive approach, if you have the `CONCAT` function, you can use the following:

*(For case-insensitive, replace `FIND` with `SEARCH`)*

```
=IF(OR(ISERR(FIND(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1),1)),1),CONCAT(" ",AllowedChars)))),"check failed", "check ok")
```

If you do not have the `CONCAT` function, replace it, in the formula, with a simple string of the allowed characters:

```
=IF(OR(ISERR(FIND(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1),1)),1)," iamnotItersd"))),"check failed", "check ok")
```

and note that some earlier versions of Excel will require that you confirm this array formula by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

- the `MID(…` function creates an array of the individual characters in the test string
- `FIND` then does a case-sensitive `FIND` of all the characters in test string against the characters in `AllowedChars`
- `FIND` will return a `#VALUE!` error if the character is not found.
- `OR(ISERR(…` will return `TRUE` if there are any failures to match.

***Edit*** further explanation:

- `ISERR(…` will return an array of Booleans `{FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE, … }` depending on whether each `FIND` is returning a number of the `#VALUE!` error
- `OR` evaluates that array and returns `TRUE` if there is any error at all.

Where AllowedChars refers to the range storing the allowed characters.

`CONCAT` ignores empty cells in a range, so we have to add the space as one of the arguments.

[image]

Comment: Sorry i cannot understand your formula. It seems that the OR doesn't have 2 condition. Just 1. Anyway if I put in array mode, it works

Comment: @user2748576 I think using CSE for entering is version specific -- not required in most recent versions of Excel.  I will add clarification about the `OR` to my answer. Check the edit in a few minutes.

Comment: @user2748576 Also, using the formula evaluation tool (on the formula tab) can be a useful method of seeing exactly what a formula is doing, or debugging it.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Now it's clear. The last question is that if I have a string like "hH" and as allowed char "h" it says check ok. If allowed char "H" it says check failed. If I have a string as "Hh" and as allowed char "h" it says check failed. If I have as allowed char "H" it says check ok. Like it evaluate just the 1st occurrence of h

Comment: @user2748576 I cannot reproduce that issue.  Are you certain you entered your formula with `ctrl-shift-enter`?

Answer (score 0):

With a **UNIQUE** list of acceptable characters in a range(I used D1:D10) one can compare the sum of the difference of removing each character and the length of the string without spaces:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,$D$1:$D$10,"")))+1 = LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))
```

This formula ignores case and the list must be a unique list of allowed characters.  `I` and `i` are the same as Excel sees it and only one can be in the list.

[image]